# Can't upload a simple .txt file on my apache server

Tags: apache-http-server, http, upload

I created an HTML form to upload a file on my own apache server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="http://localhost:8000" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p><input type="file" name="file1">

  <p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed port to listen on in Apache config, I restarted my Apache service and I opened the form and click the button to upload a .txt file.

Result: the default page of Apache appears, but when I check for the file in

> /var/www/html

there is no file.

I don't understand why the upload did not work. Any Idea ?

Comment: Creating the form is only first part. You also need a server-side script, that will accept the uploaded data and do something with them (for example store them in file). First, look up how to configure the server-side scripting, for example using PHP. Second, look up some tutorials for php form file uploading. Like this one: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp